# WooCommerce | Selling one unit at $35 although the are sold as a pack of four

Tags: woocommerce

I am just trying to setup some pricing on WooCommerce and seeing if anyone can help.

The shop is restricted to members so it is a pain I cant show you. Although here is a screenshot:

Shop example:
[image: shop example]

So the can of spray is sold at $35 each although it is sold in a pack of 4 bringing the price to $140. Although on checkout it is showing 4 items in cart when it should only be showing one...

I have tried googling things like, (selling products in units as a pack) although it just comes up with grouped products plugin which is what I am using however it shows as 4 items in the cart when it should be 1 item sold as pack of 4.

Cart sceenshot:
[image: cart]

Comment: Why would you not just list "Cream (four pack)" at a quantity of 1 for $140?

Comment: Or You could enable a "quantity" (or a "pack") attribute using variable products (even if it shows only one choice) for one variation "pack of four"…

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, ceejayoz That is exactly what I am thinking mate, but the clients wants it this way.